# Can not login to docker with docker toolbox

Tags: docker

I'm absolutely new to the docker and I want to push my docker image to docker hub. I'm running windows 7, so I have installed docker toolbox.

So, in power shell when I type: 
`docker login` it asks for a login and a password, but when I hit enter, it gives me no information if login was successful.

But when I try `docker push <image name>` 
I get an error: `denied: requested access to the resource is denied`

P.S.
If I enter incorrect login/password on `docker login`, it gives me the corresponding message

Answer (score 1):

Solved! For anyone who may faced the following issue - the problem was that windows username was written not with latin letters. Creating another user with latin name fixed that problem.